# Is this a Kendo Ui Grid bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I created Grid using Kendo Ui, and within this grid I have a detail row template. I create the main grid like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var theModel = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Datas)));
   //If the model is empty then create the No data Grid
   if (theModel.length < 1) {
       $("#AccessGrid").kendoGrid({
           columns:[
               {
                   field: "Message",
                   title: " "
               }
               ],              
           dataSource: [{Message:"No data"}]
       });
   } else {//create the normal grid
         $("#AccessGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns:[
            {
                field: "ProjNo",
                title: "Project #"
            }, 
            {
                field: "ProjType",
                title: "Job Type"
            },
            {
                field: "ProjAddress",
                title: "Address"
            }],
        selectable:true,
        scrollable:false,
        dataSource:theModel,
        detailTemplate:  kendo.template($("#AcccessDetailTemplate").html()),
        detailInit:initDetailGrid
    });
   }

});
```

and `initDetailGrid(e)` is used to create the detail grid

```
function initDetailGrid(e) {

    var grid = e.sender;

    var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); //Get the data for the selected row
    //if there are no data in intExtData then create a default obj

    if (currentDataItem.InternalData == null||currentDataItem.InternalData == undefined||currentDataItem.InternalData.length < 1 ) {           
            currentDataItem.InternalData = [{          
                TaskId:-1,
                Internal: -1,
                Sequence: -1
        }]; 
    }

    e.detailRow.find("[name='AcccessDetail']").kendoGrid({
        columns:[
           {
            field:"TaskId",
            title: "<input type='checkbox' onclick='AccessModal.checkAll(event)'/>",
            template:$("#detailInputColumnTemplate").html(),
            width: "35px"
        },
        {
            field: "Internal",
            title: " ",
            template:$("#detailColumnTemplate").html()            
        }
        ],
        scrollable:false,
        dataSource:currentDataItem.InternalData
    });      
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my detail template is not shown for one or more rows and an error is thrown saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InternalData' of null`, but how can that be? I know that there are data there, because if I refresh and click on the row detail the data shows up. This does not happen all the time , but it happens enough for me to notice. Has anyone encounter something like this before

Comment: when you click a detail button, grid must select row which include that button, but if you move your mouse, when still clicked, grid don't select any row. So `var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); `  gives error because of `grid.select()`. And in my opinion, yes it is a bug.

Comment: Especially try on chrome.hold clicking detail button,move your mouse 3 or 4 px left or right, then lift mouse.

Comment: Thank you for helping me learn how to recreate this. Maybe you can put that down as the answer and I will accept that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. You should not be relying on the selected row to get the data for your detail row. The `detailInit` event provides direct access to the row data in the `data` field of the event object passed to the handler.

Try this:

```
function initDetailGrid(e) {
    var grid = e.sender,
        dataItem = e.data;

    if (!dataItem.InternalData || dataItem.InternalData.length === 0 ) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: On some rows in my grid, caaling detailInit(e) e is undefined... Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

When you click a detail button, grid must select row which include that button, but if you move your mouse, when still clicked, grid don't select any row. So var `currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());`  gives error because of `grid.select()`. And in my opinion, yes it is a bug.Especially try on chrome.hold clicking detail button,move your mouse 3 or 4 px left or right, then lift mouse.

By the way if you have only one grid you can change selectable property as false and get clicked dataItem by `var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));`

But if you have two grid and second one binding or filtering according to selected row of first grid you must use a try catch at javascript and roll back everything.

For exp:

```
try
{
    var grid = $("#donemGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var rows = grid.select();    
    var DonemId= grid.dataItem(rows).DonemId;
    var data = grid.data("kendoGrid");
    data.dataSource.filter({ field: "DonemId", operator: "eq", value: parseInt(DonemId)
}
catch{
    //set every thing like in time before clicked
}
```